# Unable to perform merge: what is the difference in these dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes `annotatedFile` and `subOutFile` that contain similar data. I am retrieving `annotatedFile` from an xlsx file using `readxl::read_xlsx`. `subOutFile` is retrived using `read.delim2` from a tab-separated text file. They contain similar columns but `annotatedFile` has an extra column - `accuracy` that  I want to merge into the `subOutFile` dataframe

This is what the data frames look like:

[image]
[image]

My merge command was:

```
subOutFile = subOutFile %>% merge(subOutFile, annotatedFile[,c("StimName", "Accuracy")], by = "StimName", all.x = TRUE)
```

From the images above, you can see that the structure of the two dataframes looks different. One shows the vector-like notification `[1:180]` and the other does not. Is there something different about these dataframes which is why I am not able to perform the merge? Or is there another reason?

Comment: images of data, are not data... please create sample data using the output of `dput(mysampledata)` or `dput(head(mysampledata))`

Comment: Please give us some example data of the two dataframes e.g. with `dput(head(subOutFile))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `df1 %>% merge(df1, df2)`, there is one too many `df1`.

It's either `df1 <- merge(df1, df2)` or `df1 <- df1 %>% merge(df2)`. For the latter, there is a shortcut, but you will have to load the `magrittr` package: `df1 %<>% merge(df2)`.